# How do I select only visible elements using XPathin forum

Tags: xpath

I'm using XPath to identify the elements on a web page. Using the `id` attribute won't work as the id values are auto-generated and can change.

I want to know how I can access elements with `display: none;` style using following XPath expression?

```
//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/iframe
```

I tried following one, is that right?

```
#//*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/iframe{display:NONE}
```

Comment: I cleaned up your question. Is it representing what you want to ask? You cannot generally access CSS styles using XPath, please be much more specific on your problem, including example input and the code you're using to call that expression. I can already tell you that your XPath expression will be wrong, but I cannot help you to find a correct one with the information given.

Comment: I want to remove the ads using xpath  and the xpath for the ads is
 //*[@id="main-content"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/iframe

Comment: So you know the XPath expression to the advertisement, but do not know how to use it to change the value. Again, please post much more information on how what you're trying. If you only want to remove ads, using AdBlock is probably the better option than coding it yourself; it is available for all relevant browsers.

Comment: please post HTML source code.

Comment: it's too long  so this is the link
http://i-love-anime.all-up.com/forum